# Can't store attribute's value with properly type using IoTAgentUL

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I need to store the values of devices' attributes with the right type in OrionCB's MongoDB.

As I was unable to perform that I dived into the code and found that IoTAgentUL (as well as IoTAgentJSON) uses OrionCB's `API v1` instead of `API v2`.

As I can see `API v1`'s [updateContext](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/walkthrough_apiv1/#update-context-elements) sends data to MongoDB **without** it's type, so every measure is stored as text.

In the other hand I found that `API v2`'s [update entity](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html) send data to MongoDB **with** it's type. It produces that I can store attribute's values with it's type which benefits me when manipulating data (i.e. creating indexes, sorting, etc).

My question is if is there any workaround to solve this using the current implementations of IoT Agents.

Comment: In my opinion, I do not see any problem with the types saved as text. It is just needed to make a test when using the values. If it is already known, the test is not needed. If the application does not know what kind of data it is dealing with, just do a test to see the type and take the specific decision.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can imagine is, once entities are automatically created by the IoT Agents, to update the type of such entities by your own. I mean, AFAIK, you can update both the value and the type of an entity.

In more details, I can think on a script that subscribes for all entities of certain type (those created by the agents). Then, when an entity is created this is notified to the script, which automatically updates the type of the entity's attributes.

Please observe you only need to modify the attribute's types once, just when the entities are created, not when an entity's attribute is updated; thus, something like an array or cache of already modified entities is needed in your script.